# MATLAB: parfor error

Tags: matlab, for-loop, iteration, parfor

I have the following MATLAB code that I want to run it by using parfor:

```
max = -1;
for i = 1:10
    for j = (i+1):10
       X = my_function(i, j);
       if (X > max)
           max = X;
       end
    end
end
disp(max)
```

I want to change the first for to parfor. I read couple of tutorials and the documentation, but I don't know how to have the same result for max, by using parfor.

I know that there is some problem with the usage of i in `for j = (i+1):10`.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: You don't. You save all of the `X` values in an array and find the `max` afterwards. It's also a very bad idea to name a variable the same as a built-in function. It makes using the function again a bit of a pain.

Comment: Including your error/warning messages may be a good idea to obtain better answers and a reusable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can not use `parfor` for dependent iterations](https://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/decide-when-to-use-parfor.html), i.e. in your case `max` is a dependent (shared) variable between your loop iterations:

> You cannot use a parfor-loop when an iteration in your loop depends on
>   the results of other iterations. Each iteration must be independent of
>   all others.

This is also reflected in the displayed warning message:

> Warning: The temporary variable `max` will be cleared at the beginning
>   of each iteration of the parfor loop. Any value assigned to it before
>   the loop will be lost.  If `max` is used before it is assigned in the
>   parfor loop, a runtime error will occur. See Parallel for Loops in
>   MATLAB, "Temporary Variables".

MATLAB implements [one exception to this rule](https://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/decide-when-to-use-parfor.html), i.e. [Reduction Variables](https://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/reduction-variable.html):

> The exception to this rule is
>   to accumulate values in a loop using [Reduction Variables](https://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/reduction-variable.html).

So, you can rewrite your code to use reduction variables:

```
maxX = -1;
for i = 1:10
    for j = (i+1):10
       maxX = max(maxX, my_function(i, j));
    end
end
disp(maxX)
```